# ArrayAdaper with 2 different ArrayList types NullPointerException while initializing with EDGE connection

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I'm using ArrayAdapter with different types :

```
public class GeoStreetsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> implements Filterable {
     public GeoStreetsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<GeoStreet> data, ArrayList<GeoObject> geoObjects ) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.context = context;
        this.geoStreets = data;
        this.geoObjects = geoObjects;
    }
}
```

When I initialize the adapter in the `onPostExecute` of the AsyncTask, I get the `NullPointerException` on the line :

```
final GeoStreetsAdapter adapter = new GeoStreetsAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.auto_complete_item,
                    geoStreets, geoObjects );
```

That is weird, because it happens not at all devices and most of all, when I'm using the EDGE connection. When I'm using Wi Fi - everything works fine.

Error :

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       adapters.GeoStreetsAdapter.<init> (GeoStreetsAdapter.java:24)
    codenest.testaplication.EnterStreetFragment$GetStreetName.onPostExecute (EnterStreetFragment.java:258)
    codenest.testaplication.EnterStreetFragment$GetStreetName.onPostExecute (EnterStreetFragment.java:166)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly why people is minusing, besides it is quite actual problem. Nevertheless, I found the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a solution with progressDialog, but found a solution with ProgressBar. Maybe will be useful for somebody :

Put the ProgressBar inside the layout with the GONE visability :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    ....>

    <EditText
       ...
    <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/streets_progress"
        android:visibility="gone"

        />
    <ListView
        ....
        /> </RelativeLayout>
```

In the AsyncTask :

```
 @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            streets_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            if (result!=null) {
            streets_progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

The keyboard keeps visible.